# Spaces in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file in which I write, which doesn't work

```
set num_args = 0
```

but

```
set num_args=0
```

works.

If this is a property of batch file, it's fine. Can we somehow override this to make the batch file look more elegant.

Edit: Batch file in windows.

Comment: Is this a question about Windows? In most Unix scripting languages, like bash, the spaces are not legal.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, those aren't the same.

This:

```
set num_args = 0
```

creates a variable called "num_args " with the value " 0" (note the spaces), whereas this:

```
set num_args=0
```

creates a variable called "num_args" with the value "0".

Answer (score 1):

You can define a procedure to do an assignment (somewhere outside of a scope of a main program). Something like this:

```
:ASSIGN [VarName] [Value]
    call set %~1=%~2
    exit /B 0
```

Use it like this:

```
call :ASSIGN num_args 0
call :ASSIGN some_var 1
call :ASSIGN text_var "A text with spaces in it."
```